# Object in ArrayList is changing

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I made a test program because I am trying to get back into Java after working in PL/SQL. I created a class Numbers that contains an integer, a getter and a setter. I have another class Test that is creating an instance of Numbers, and also adds that instance to a List. I created a for loop that loops two times and sets the value of the integer in Numbers equal to i. I then add that instance of Numbers to the List numbersList. I then do a print screen of the value that was added to the List. I do a total of 3 prints, one print the first time through the loop that prints the first position in the List, then I print two times during the second time through the loop,the first position in the List again, and the second position in the List. I was expecting to get 0,0,1 as the result. I am getting instead 0,1,1 as the result and I cannot figure out why. I am not changing anything in the first position in the List (numbersList[0]) during the second time through the loop, all I am doing is adding an instance of Numbers into the second position in the list (numbersList[1]).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tests {
    static int x;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Numbers> numbersList = new ArrayList<Numbers>();
        Numbers numbers = new Numbers();
        Numbers numbers2 = new Numbers();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                numbers.setVariable(i);
                numbersList.add(numbers);
                System.out.println(numbersList.get(0).getVariable());
            }

            if (i > 0) {
                numbers2.setVariable(i);
                numbersList.add(numbers2);
                System.out.println(numbersList.get(0).getVariable());
                System.out.println(numbersList.get(1).getVariable());
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Numbers {
    public static int a = 5;

    public static void setVariable(int b) {
        a = b;
    }

    public static int getVariable() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`public static int a = 5` means that all instances of `Numbers` share the same variable because of the `static` keyword.

Therefore, when you do `numbers2.setVariable(i);`, the variable is also changed for `numbers`. Hence the `0,1,1`

If you want instance variables remove the `static` keywords from `Numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `Numbers` has no instance fields (everything is `static`, or class level).

It should look something like (and overriding `toString()` is a good idea),

```
public class Numbers {
   public int a = 5;

   public void setVariable(int b){
         a = b;
   }
   public int getVariable(){
        return a;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(a);
   }
}
```

By overriding `toString()` you can more easily print instances of `Numbers`. For example,

```
System.out.println(numbersList);
```